# Gradle does not import groovy class when running task

Tags: gradle, groovy, import, build, build.gradle

I have a gradle (1.8) project with 2 classes A and B where B import A. Both files are under `/foo/bar/` package (myProjectFolder/test/foo/bar folder).

**A.groovy class**

```
package foo.bar

import org.junit.Test;

public class ATest{ 
    @Test
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("CLASS A");
    }
}
```

**B.groovy class**

```
package foo.bar

import org.junit.Test;

public class BTest{
    @Test
    public void run() {
        ATest a = new ATest();
        a.run();
        System.out.println("CLASS B");
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        groovy group: "org.codehaus.groovy", name:"groovy-all", version: "1.8.6"
        testCompile "junit:junit:4.10"
}

test {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

sourceSets {
        test { groovy {
                srcDir 'test/foo/bar'
        } }
}

buildscript {
        repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

configurations{
    addToClassLoader
}

dependencies {
    addToClassLoader "junit:junit:4.10"
}

URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
configurations.addToClassLoader.each {File file ->

loader.addURL(file.toURL())
}

task runA << {
    new GroovyShell().run(file('test/foo/bar/ATest.groovy'));
}

task runB << {
    new GroovyShell().run(file('test/foo/bar/BTest.groovy'));
}
```

Output console for `gradle clean -Dtest.single=A test`

```
[root@vm1]# gradle clean -Dtest.single=A test
The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
foo.bar.ATest > run STANDARD_OUT
    CLASS A
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13.205 secs
```

Output console for `gradle clean -Dtest.single=B test`

```
[root@vm1]# gradle clean -Dtest.single=B test
The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
foo.bar.BTest > run STANDARD_OUT
    CLASS A
    CLASS B
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 12.218 secs
```

Output console for `gradle -q runA -i`

```
[root@vm1]# gradle -q runA -i
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/opt/myProject/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'myProject']
Evaluating root project 'myProject' using build file '/opt/myProject/build.gradle'.
Starting file lock listener thread.
The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'runA'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':runA']
:runA (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:runA
Executing task ':runA' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
CLASS A
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 0, Time: 63
:runA (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.739 secs.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 7.826 secs
```

Output console for `gradle -q runB -i` **<-- THIS EXECUTION FAILS** and I don't know why.

```
[root@vm1]# gradle -q runB -i
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/opt/myProject/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'myProject']
Evaluating root project 'myProject' using build file '/opt/myProject/build.gradle'.
Starting file lock listener thread.
The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'runB'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':runB']
:runB (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:runB
Executing task ':runB' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
:runB FAILED
:runB (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.237 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/opt/myProject/build.gradle' line: 46
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runB'.
> startup failed:
  /opt/myProject/test/foo/bar/BTest.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class ATest
   @ line 8, column 9.
                ATest a = new ATest();
             ^
  /opt/myProject/test/foo/bar/BTest.groovy: 8: unable to resolve class ATest
   @ line 8, column 13.
                ATest a = new ATest();
                 ^
  2 errors
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 7.872 secs
```

So, what am I missing to run the task runB correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why are you trying to run tests *by hand* and in a different path to the norm?  Why not just stick them in `src/test/groovy` and get rid off all the sourceset stuff and your extra tasks and your classloader stuff and just run `gradle test`...  I assume you have your reasons for going so far off the beaten path, but I can't see them, and explaining how to do so without making sure it's the right thing seems foolhardy

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** the premise of the question is based on a truly unorthodox use-case, which should be corrected. That said, I can explain the behaviour that is observed.

When the command-line specifies the `test` task, then `~/build/classes/test` is added to the classpath. In the case of running the `runB` task, it is not. So `BTest.groovy` can't find `ATest`.

To correct it (*only as an illustration*, **not** as a suggestion for 'real' code), consider:

```
// don't do this in a real project!
task runB(dependsOn: 'compileTestGroovy') << {
    def testDirURL = new File("${projectDir}/build/classes/test").toURL()
    loader.addURL(testDirURL)
    new GroovyShell(loader).run(file('test/foo/bar/BTest.groovy'))
}
```

Now, `runB` requires that the Groovy test code is compiled, and then manually (!?) adds it to the classloader used by GroovyShell.